# Why child class inherit convenience initializer when overriding all designated initializer?

Tags: swift

```
class Parent {
    var a : Int
    init(a : Int) {
        self.a =a
    }
    convenience init() {
        self.init(a : 10)
    }
}
class Child : Parent {
    var b : Int
    override init(a : Int){
        b = 10
        super.init(a : a)
    }
}

var child = Child() // i know that convenience initializer is inherited, but why??
child.a // 10
child.b // 10
```

i know that convenience initializer is inherited, but why??
Just I override all designated initializer? so why is it need?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you're asking here. Why shouldn't they be inherited in this case? All of the superclass' designated initialisers (in this case, just `init(a:)`) are accessible on `Child`, so all of the superclass' convenience initialisers are valid to call on `Child` (as they *delegate* to the designated initialisers).

Comment: I know that is the rule. but why superclass's convenience initialisers are valid to call on child. because they delegate to the designated initialiser?

Comment: Yes, precisely.

Answer (score 3):

This is the rule as described in [The Swift Programming Language](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH18-ID222):

> **Rule 2**
>   If your subclass provides an implementation of all of its superclass designated initializers—either by inheriting them as per rule 1, or by providing a custom implementation as part of its definition—then it automatically inherits all of the superclass convenience initializers.

Inheriting convenience initializers is not *needed* if clients of the subclass don’t want to use them (just like inheriting methods and properties is not *needed* if clients of subclasses don’t use them), but it is the natural thing to do in my opinion.

Inheriting all of the superclass’s API is the default for subclasses, so convenience initializers should be inherited as well if possible. Since convenience initializers are required to call a sibling designated initializer, the compiler can be sure that all properties will be properly initialized only if all designated initializers are overridden in the subclass.

Comment: um.. I know It is the rule. But I don't know why need this rule.